# Подключение лазерного дальномера по протоколу RS232 (MODBUS RTU\)

Tags: rs232, modbus, uart, электроника

Имеется лазерный дальномер sndway swlds50a, работающий по физическому протоколу RS232/RS485 (MODBUS RTU). В комплекте стандартный софт снимающий показания измерений. Но подключенный дальномер(подключал и по RS232 и 485) не дает никаких показаний, словно его нет. Хотя луч лазера виден и устройство работает. Также пробовал сканировать порт при помощи т.н. Modbus сканера, перебирающего все скорости и адреса с целью найти подключенное устройство. 0 результатов. В распиновке помимо VCC/GND и стандартных сигнальных выходов RX,TX,SGND также есть некоторый HT выход, с таким описанием: "HT: аппаратный сигнал запуска (спадающий фронт запускает одно измерение)". Переведя всю инструкцию с китайского так нигде и не нашел дальнейшего упоминания об это выходе. Необходимо ли его подключение? И каким образом он должен быть подключен? Может ли отсутствие его подключения быть причиной того, что устройство не было обнаружено сканером modbus?
PS. параметры работы последовательного порта, такие как четность и стоповый бит задавались согласно инструкции устройства.

Comment: Не уверен, но из Вашего описания можно предположить, что подключение данного сигнала необходимо. Как мне  кажется, он должен быть подключен высоким уровнем, и должен быть обеспечено управление им для генерации спадающего фронта. Без этого (вероятно) дальномер не выполнит измерение, и ничего не передаст по каналу связи. Возможно поэтому-же он и не обнаруживается сканером.

Comment: У вас RS232 встроенный или переходник USB-RS232? Еще есть вариант что RS232 банально сгорел. Посмотрите осциллографом, сигналы на RS232 на передатчике во время сканирования, там должны идти посылки. В системе RS232 виден? Какая система - винда или линукс?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 переходник, несколько разных на выбор. В системе (Windows) отображаются, драйвера актуальные. При сканировании мигает светодиод на переходнике.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Я сейчас подключил к HT цифровой выход от ардуины, который "мигает" раз секунду. Что соответственно должно запускать измерение ежесекундно. Жаль в инструкции ни слова об электрическом уровне для данного выхода. Но 5 вольт должно быть достаточно. Жаль результата это не дало.

Comment: @ПашаСаенко, а инструкцию можно где-то увидеть? Найти с разбегу не смог

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов. В комплекте идет напечатанная инструкция и диск с такой же но в  PDF. Но обе на китайском. Я на обменник залил. https://dropmefiles.com/PWYgn

Comment: @ПашаСаенко, обратите внимание - VCC +8-+1V, может и НТ такого же уровня нужен?

Comment: Светодиод не показатель. Светодиод будет мигать даже если порт сгорел. Если у Вас переходник USB-RS232, то учтите, что там большие задержки по сравнению со встроенным RS232. Команды передаются сначала по USB, а только потом отрабатываются на стороне RS232. Из-за этого временная диаграмма будет не такой, как в случае встроенного RS232. Моргающий светодиод показывает, что ПО обращается куда нужно. Но сам порт может быть сгоревшим. Либо смотрите сигналы осциллографом, либо возьмите другой порт RS232, соедините два порта нуль-модемным кабелем и попихайте байты туда-сюда с помощью терминала.

Comment: в моем комменте выше - опечатка. Не VCC +8-+1V,  а VCC +8-+12V. Прошу прощения

Answer (score 0):

Мобдас RTU поверх RS232 может еще использовать сигналы на пинах RTS/CTS, в зависимости от реализации, и не все переходники USB-serial позволяют управлять ими, возможно подключение к нормальному компорту проблему решит. Еще один нюанс, RS485 и RS232 используют разные контакты на колодке. В настройках устройства это как то выбирается или нет? неплохо было бы глянуть на список переменных, доступных через модбас, если они есть в документации, возможно запись в какой-нибудь регистр тоже может служить триггером для запуска измерения. и вернет результат в один из доступных регистров?